# Magento set Dynamic price

Tags: magento

I need to manage price according to hours(qty). Conditions are given below:

> €60 per hour and
>       from 20h it will be €55
>       from 30h it will be €50
>       from 60h it will be €45

Please help me with this.

Comment: you need to set a cron job, which will update price manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up as price rules, where you get discount when qty is above the limits you set. It might not show directly on the product page, but would show in the cart/checkout and you can add an explanation to the product description.